# Can I switch faction once I have chosen one?

Tags: heroes-and-generals

If I have chosen a faction in Heroes and Generals, can I change this faction at a later stage (before the "war" has ended?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will have to wait till the current war is over before you can change factions.

[Source:Official Wiki](https://heroesandgenerals.gamepedia.com/Factions)